# Python Pandas Dataframe - What is the fastest way to convert data into NaN if flag is '1'?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the fastest way to convert the data into NaN if the flag is "1"?

There are Dataframes which indicate the data and flags.
Those frames have hundreds of columns and a half a million number of records.

```
 df
                    S_1  S_2  ... S_n
2016-01-01 00:00    5.6  0.4  ... 6.7
2016-01-01 00:00    5.5  0.2  ... 6.6
2016-01-01 00:00    5.0  0.2  ... 6.7
....
2016-12-31 23:57    5.4  0.3  ... 6.7
2016-12-31 23:58    5.9  0.3  ... 6.8
2016-12-31 23:59    5.1  0.4  ... 7.0

 flag_table
                    S_1  S_2  ... S_n
2016-01-01 00:00      0    0  ...   1
2016-01-01 00:00      0    0  ...   0
2016-01-01 00:00      1    0  ...   0
....
2016-12-31 23:57      1    0  ...   0
2016-12-31 23:58      1    0  ...   1
2016-12-31 23:59      1    0  ...   0
```

This is a table that I would like to get:

```
 df
                    S_1  S_2  ... S_n
2016-01-01 00:00    5.6  0.4  ... NaN
2016-01-01 00:00    5.5  0.2  ... 6.6
2016-01-01 00:00    NaN  0.2  ... 6.7
....
2016-12-31 23:57    NaN  0.3  ... 6.7
2016-12-31 23:58    NaN  0.3  ... NaN
2016-12-31 23:59    NaN  0.4  ... 7.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.values[flag_table > 0] = np.nan
```